# Máximo e mínimo Python

Tags: python, funções

Qual é a função que eu uso para encontrar os valores máximo e mínimo entre 2 valores na linguagem Python? Obrigada

Comment: `lambda (x,y): x if x > y else y`

Answer (score 13):

Para o minimo tem a função `min` e para o máximo tem a função `max`.

Elas podem ser utilizadas sobre 2 (ou mais) valores, o caso da pergunta:

```
menor = min(2,8) # 2
maior = max(2,8) # 8
```

Ou sobre um iterável:

```
lista = [1, 8, 2, 4, 9]

menor = min(lista) # 1
maior = max(lista) # 9
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/tskU8i)

Documentação para a função [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) e para a função [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

---

Para o exemplo simples de máximo ou minimo de 2 valores até podia fazer "á mão" com base num `if`:

```
x = 2
y = 8

menor = x if x < y else y # 2
maior = x if x > y else y # 8
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/6U4U2U)

Answer (score 9):

A **título de curiosidade**, você pode implementar a função de forma matemática. É [possível demonstrar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46939/modus-operandi-formulae-for-maximum-and-minimum-of-two-numbers-with-a-b-and) que:

```
max{a, b} = 0.5 (a + b + |a - b|)
```

e

```
min{a, b} = 0.5 (a + b - |a - b|)
```

Então em Python, uma solução seria:

```py
def minmax(a, b):
    return 0.5*(a+b+abs(a-b)), 0.5*(a+b-abs(a-b))

print(minmax(7, 3)) # (3.0, 7.0)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/tnVRXq) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LpNR/0)</sup>

Na prática, prefira utilizar as funções `min` e `max` apontadas pelo [Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/241709/5878).

Comment: +1. Muito interessante essa dedução matemática para o máximo e minimo que eu pessoalmente desconhecia.

Comment: @Isac para deixar mais interessante ainda, será que é possível expandir para mais de dois números?

Comment: Eu acho que deve ser, vou ver se consigo expandir a lógica para 3 elementos e potêncialmente deduzir uma função para N elementos numa forma de serie

Comment: Para 3 elementos é fácil. Fica: `max(a,b,c) = 0.5(a + 0.5(b + c + | b - c|) + | a - 0.5(b + c + |b - c|)|)`, ou em código já `def max(a,b,c):
 return 0.5*(a+0.5*(b+c+abs(b-c))+abs(a-0.5*(b+c+abs(b-c))))`. Agora para N parece me já mais complicado

Answer (score 1):

Oi,

Máximo: max()
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

Mínimo: min()
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min